# Is there a way to disable log message that is from module I use?

Tags: python, logging, module

In my code, I have a few debug lines using logging modules.

However, when running the program, I saw a lot of other debug messages that is not from my code.

Looks like it is from the other modules that I use in the code, is there a way to disable the log (debug) messages that is not from my code (modules)?

If not, what is usually the common practice?

Answer (score 0):

`logging.setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)` will disable pretty much all non-critial logging accross all loggers (I think at least...)

after that you can set your logger to have a more reasonable threshold

`logging.getLogger("my_logger").setLevel(logging.DEBUG)`

I think that should work ... without extensively testing it at all